# Jersey: How to get the URI of a resource?

Tags: java, uri, jersey-1.0

[ResourceContext.matchResource(URI)](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceContext.html#matchResource%28java.net.URI%29) allows me to convert a URI to a Resource, but how do I go from a Resource to its URI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
@Context UriInfo uriInfo;

public URI getUri()
{
  return uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder().path(MyResource.class).build();
}
```